# Issue with PersistentBottomNavBar: MediaQuery.of(context)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some issues with PersistentBottomNavBar package in my Flutter App. It gives me an error with MediaQuery.of(context) message: 'it called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery'. I can't imagine what's going on here. Maybe it's because I'm using persistentBottomNavbar inside MultiProvider widget? I've tried to get rid of MultiProvider with MaterialApp widgets and return only PersistentTabView widget as a build widget. But it couldn't help me.

The code I have:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import './providers/products.dart';

import './screens/words_list_screen.dart';
import './screens/add_word_screen.dart';
import './screens/profile_screen.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PersistentTabController _tabController;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Products(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sample App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
          accentColor: Colors.grey[700],
          errorColor: Colors.red[400],
          fontFamily: 'Nunito',
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: PersistentTabView(
          context,
          controller: _tabController,
          screens: [
            ProductsListScreen(),
            AddProductScreen(),
            ProfileScreen(),
          ],
          items: _navBarItems(),
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          stateManagement: true,
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.red,
          ),
          popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          ),
          screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
            animateTabTransition: true,
            curve: Curves.ease,
            duration: Duration(
              milliseconds: 200,
            ),
          ),
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So in my Android Emulator I have following issues with red screen.

[image: Have this kinda error in my Android-emulator]

Also in my debug-console in VCode.

[image: Have this error in my debug-terminal window in vcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove MaterialApp from MyApp widget and make it the parent Widget of MyApp widget by adding the MaterialApp in your runApp. Your code should look similar to this code below

```
......
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Products(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sample App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
          accentColor: Colors.grey[700],
          errorColor: Colors.red[400],
          fontFamily: 'Nunito',
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PersistentTabController _tabController;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
```

......

Or you may make a separate Widget just for MaterialApp.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Now I have another error(( `The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Flexible>(Closure: (PersistentBottomNavBarItem) => Flexible)
`

Comment: This error is seems to be unrelated to the original question. This error seems to be in the _navBarItems() function where you are calling map on some variable. Will have to see more code to find where that error is from. If you think the MediaQuery.of error has been solved please try to debug the code and find where you are calling map in _navBarItems() .

Comment: If you think I solved your original question you could like and accept it and may be post a new question with some example code of your current error.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278583/flutter-something-is-wrong-with-persistentbottomnavbar-package) I posted my current issue.